# Unexpected argument in PyCharm for the ttkbootstrap bootstyle argument

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, ttkbootstrap

I got an "Unexpected argument" warning in PyCharm when using the ttkbootstrap's bootstyle argument.

The following code works but I couldn't fix the warning.

```
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

root = ttk.Window()

b1 = ttk.Button(root, text="Button 1", bootstyle=SUCCESS)
b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)

b2 = ttk.Button(root, text="Button 2", bootstyle=(INFO, OUTLINE))
b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use style instead like so. No warning in pycharm and works like a charm:

```py
    b1 = ttk.Button(root, text="Button 1", style=SUCCESS)
    b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)

    b2 = ttk.Button(root, text="Button 2", style=f'{INFO},{OUTLINE}')
    b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)

    b3 = ttk.Button(root, text="Button 2", style=f'{TTK_DEFAULT}, {OUTLINE}')
    b3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)
```

However, this is not a recommended use of `ttkbootstrap` as per the [tutorial](https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/tutorial/), which brings `bootstyle` parameter, a replacement for `style`.

The reason behind the PyCharm warning stands in the way how `ttkbootstrap` is designed and implemented.
On first glance, the `ttkbootstrap.Button` is a class of `ttk.Button`, and this is what PyCharm sees and utilizes for Warnings about correct/incorrect params. However, during the runtime, the `import ttkbootstrap` overrides the widgets constructors by its own `ttkbootstrap` generic constructor adding the `bootstyle` param.

The runtime constructor for `ttkbootstrap` widgets:

```py
    @staticmethod
    def override_ttk_widget_constructor(func):
        """Override widget constructors with bootstyle api options.

        Parameters:

            func (Callable):
                The widget class `__init__` method
        """

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

            # capture bootstyle and style arguments
            if "bootstyle" in kwargs:
                bootstyle = kwargs.pop("bootstyle")
            else:
                bootstyle = ""

            if "style" in kwargs:
                style = kwargs.pop("style") or ""
            else:
                style = ""
    ...
```

The style/bootstyle are both used.

While one could argue this implementation is elegant in my opinion it brings confusion and makes IDEs such as PyCharm trigger false Warnings.

Comment: Can you please explain why the warning is raised and why your approach works? It will make your answer more useful to future readers

Comment: I agree. Although the suggested solution works, it would be nice to understand the reason for this warning.

Comment: Expanded the answer as per suggestions.